# appendTo and remove not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The following snippet of html and jquery works in:
Firefox, Safari and Chrome, both in OSX and XP (all browsers latest production updates.

I'm using the java debugger in safari, firefox and IE8

But in IE8, the contents of CCC is not moved!!
I do not have IE6 or IE7 to test with.

```
<html>
<head>   </head>
<body>
   <div class="AAA">
      <div class="BBB">  </div>
   </div>

   <div class="CCC">
      <div id="0">   <img src="image/..." />  </div>
      <div id="1">   <img src="image/..." />  </div>
   </div>
</html>
```

jquery code is in a separate file:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
   // move div's contained within class="CCC" to class="BBB"
   $('.CCC div).each(function() {
      $(this).appendTo('.AAA .BBB');
});
```

At the completion of this function, class "CCC" will have no content.

I also tried remove.  I get the same results in IE8 (not working).

After executing "var temp" line, each div in the loop should be removed.  I'm looking in the debugger "html view" to verify this.

```
$(.CCC div).each(function() {
    var temp = ('.CCC div:eq(0)').remove();
    temp.appendTo('BBB');
});
```

Comment: Is this code copy/pasted or retyped because there are a lot of typos. In your first jQuery segment you are doing a selector statement but not terminating the string constant $('.CCC div) <- missing ' before ). In the second block you have no string at all in outermost selector and no jQuery marker ($) in the inner selector.

Answer (score 1):

i think you are missing a $

```
 var temp = $('.CCC div:eq(0)').remove();
```

Comment: Yes, it was a typo in this post.  The $ is in my code.  Otherwise it would not have worked in the other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to do this when the document is ready and not on window load.
Also, console.log anywhere in your code will "kill" JS if you are using Firefox without Firebug and probably (although i'm not sure) IE.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   // move div's contained within class="CCC" to class="BBB"
   $('.CCC div').each(function() {
      $(this).appendTo('.BBB'); //.AAA is not necessary if you want to append to all instances of .BBB
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "console.log will 'kill' JS"? I use console.log all the time with no issues.

Comment: So what do we need $(window).load() for ?

Sometimes you want to manipulate pictures. For example you want to verticaly and horizontaly align a picture and you need to get the width and height of the picture in order to do that. With $(document).ready() you won’t be able to do that if the visitor doesn’t have the image already loaded, in which case you need to initialize the jquery alignment function when the image finishes loading.

Comment: I found this tip: So what do we need $(window).load() for ?

Sometimes you want to manipulate pictures. For example you want to verticaly and horizontaly align a picture and you need to get the width and height of the picture in order to do that. With $(document).ready() you won’t be able to do that if the visitor doesn’t have the image already loaded, in which case you need to initialize the jquery alignment function when the image finishes loading.

Comment: class "CCC" contains images with each one encapsulated in its own div.  Once these are moved to "BBB", each of the images are aligned (placed on top of the first one) by using offset().top method.  Opacity is then used to animate a thumbnail click images to opacity of 1 and the previous image to zero.  Using what you suggested, "CCC" moved to "BBB" but the offset().top broke on Safari, chrome and IE8.  I need to wait until the full DOM to load before I move any images.  Look at http://web.enavu.com/daily-tip/daily-tip-difference-between-document-ready-and-window-load-in-jquery/

Comment: @Hollister: console.log in firefox without firebug installed will cause an error in JS, this will cause JS to stop running. That's what I mean by console.log will "kill" JS. I'm not sure about IE6 and IE7 (ietester fails but I have not tried in the native environment). @user500881 you are right and that's actually a great tip thank you i had no idea it could be used that way.

Comment: @bmarti44: Ah, well I wouldn't use `console.log()` if I *wasn't* running Firebug.